# How to access built-in ribbon controls in Outlook addin 2010

Tags: outlook

I have created a ribbon control called 'RBS' with type as 
RibbonType.Appointment

If i click on the 'Appointment'/'New Meeting' in the calendar window, along with the built-in groups, 'RBS' option also get listed out.

I want to set 'RBS' as selected by default while opening 'New Apponitment'/'New  Meeting', for this i want to access built-in tab controls, I have tried as like below,

```
ThisRibbonCollection ribbonCollection =
Globals.Ribbons
[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()];
```

but which always pulls out the created ribbon item for all types of inspector.

pls let me know how to access buitl-in tab controls say like 'Appointment' which is selected by default if we click on 'New Appointment'/'New Meeting'

Comment: kindly let me know for any solution

Comment: Do you mean you are creating a toggleButton control and want to make it pressed by default?

Comment: yes, I already created togglebutton using ribbon designer and assigned ribbon type as appointment, but now i want only my button to be selected by default, so wants to access existing built-in toggle buttons to change its property?

Comment: Have you specified the getPressed callback for your button?

Comment: can you pls post me sample code for calling that callback function

Comment: I am not using Ribbon.Xml, instead using Ribbon Designer, how to implement the getpressed in ribbonm designer?